# EF Core: Return only related date two levels down

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I got a simple setup where i am trying to get 2nd level child entities based on parent entity.

Example

```
public class Country {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<State> States {get;set;}
}

public class State {
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public Country Country {get;set;}
 public List<City> Cities {get;set;}
}

public class City {
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public State State {get;set;}
}
```

How do i retrieve only Cities (essentially ignoring all other information) that have parent with Country.Name == "Japan"?

I know of ThenInclude:

```
dbContext.Countries
.Include(o => o.States}
.ThenInclude(x => x.Cities)
.Where(o => o.Name.Equals("Japan"))
.ToList();
```

Then i have to extact each city list and combine it into new list which contains List only (which i don't think is elegant way).

Comment: For this use case, the number of cities is a pretty finite number. I would flatten this to two tables anyways. Countries table would be pretty small, 195 records.  If you stuck to cities with over 100k inhabitants (which is pretty good for general purposes) would be at most 5000 records for that table, which SQL would be able to handle very easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the simplest most way to do this is to look at it from reverse.

```
 await dbContext.Cities
       .Where(o => o.State.Country.Name.Equals("Japan"))
       .ToListAsync();
```

This will return ONLY list of cities that have a grand-parent with name Japan.

Comment: Might be the right idea, but your code isn't correct, it doesn't even compile.

Comment: @GertArnold yea deleted a where by accident when prettifying the answer. This is the working piece i got.

Comment: You want to update the question at first place. You can hardly traverse from City object to State and Country.

Comment: I just realised half the relationships were missing in the code example. Fixed it up, it should all make sense now.